# ASP.Net Facebook Web Applicatoin

Tags: c#, asp.net, facebook, authorization

I have been looking to tutorials/samples/examples on creating a facebook web app using .net (preferably C#) and it seems as all that exists are razor mvc apps. Is there a reason why no developers are not creating simple web apps on .net without the razor mvc?

Any links to any web apps that don't use razor or mvc would be appreciated.

Thanks

This is really to just cover the basics of intergration between facebook and the app i am to create(asp.net web app)

Answer (score 0):

I know that the majority of app tutorials are using the razor template, but picking up bits and pieces I have managed to integrate a standard MVC4 Facebook app.  The first thing you need is a standard MVC 4 template and add the Facebook package through the NuGet manager.

Enter your Facebook app details into the Web.Config

```
<add key="Facebook:AppId" value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
<add key="Facebook:AppSecret" value="xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx" />
<add key="Facebook:AppNamespace" value="" />
<add key="Facebook:AuthorizationRedirectPath" value="~/Home/Permissions" />
<add key="Facebook:VerifyToken:User" value="" />
```

Your home Controller should look something like this

```
[FacebookAuthorize("email")]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index(FacebookContext context)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            Session["FacebookToken"] = context.AccessToken;
            var user = await context.Client.GetCurrentUserAsync<AppUser>();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Account");
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Error", "Home");
    }

    // This action will handle the redirects from FacebookAuthorizeFilter when 
    // the app doesn't have all the required permissions specified in the FacebookAuthorizeAttribute.
    // The path to this action is defined under appSettings (in Web.config) with the key 'Facebook:AuthorizationRedirectPath'.
    public ActionResult Permissions(FacebookRedirectContext context)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(context);
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Error", "Home");
    }

    public ActionResult FacebookInit()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }

    public ActionResult Error()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

While the most important piece of code (and the bit that caused me the most problems) being

```
var client = new FacebookClient(Session["FacebookToken"].ToString());
dynamic me = client.Get("me");
```

This should get you started and the Facebook API guide should help you with the various user details that you can access.